# Finding isomorphism between quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_3 = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, p(x) = x^2 + 1, q(x) = x^2+x+2$ and show that $$\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(p(x)) \cong \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(q(x))$$

Why is $\phi:\mathbb{F}_3[x] \to \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(q(x))$ given by $\phi(x) = x+2$ such an isomorphism? It doesn't seem to follow from the first isomorphism theorem unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: $p(x+2)=q(x)$ in $\Bbb F_3[x]$.

Answer (score 3):

Both quotient rings are fields of order $9$ since both $x^2+1$ and $x^2+x+2$ are irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$. Since any two
fields of order $p^n$ are isomorphic, the claim follows. Of course, we can verify this directly by giving a bijective homomorphism of quotient rings (see Fabios's remark).

Answer (score 0):

For this specific isomorphism, I think there's a small error in the formula.
Denote \xi the congruence class of $x\bmod x^2+1$ and set $\eta=\varphi(\xi)=\xi-2=\xi+1$. Obviously $\mathbf F_3(\xi)=\mathbf F_3(\eta)$.

We'll determine the minimal polynomial of $\eta$ from the minimal polynomial of $\xi\,$:
$$0=\xi^2+1=(\eta+2)^2+1=(\eta^2+4\eta+4)+1=\eta^2+\eta+2,$$
so  $\;\mathbf F_3(\xi)=\mathbf F_3(\eta)\simeq \mathbf F_3[X]/(X^2+X+2)$.